# JQuery Chosen scrolling bug

Tags: jquery-chosen

I use a jquery chosen multiselect box with multiple options and optgroups. There are so many options that there is a scrollbar when showing all of them (when clicking on the select box).

When I'm at the bottom of the option list and I simply scroll down a few entries the focus moves back to the last element and the lists scrolls back to the bottom so that I'm unable to simply scroll to the options in the center.

Any ideas where this might come from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle link that shows the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as if the plugin won't work with jQuery 2.X - with 1.12 it worked fine